# Why does Solve not solve these two coupled equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I have two simple coupled equations

```
eqn1 = 0 == -x + P - G x (y + 1);
eqn2 = 0 == -y + G x (y + 1);
```

If I use `Solve[eqn1 && eqn2, y]` I get no result. But I can force Mathematica to give me the result by solving `eqn1` for `x` and then substituting that into `eqn2` and solving for `y`

```
Simplify[Solve[eqn2, y] /. Solve[eqn1, x]]
```

which gives the result `y -> (G P)/(1 + G (1 - P + y))`.

Why does the single pass of `Solve` not work; and can I make it work?

Comment: I think I've seen a few more problems when solving for n equations with m unknowns and m!=n

Comment: Try `Solve[{0 == -x + P - G x (y + 1), 0 == -y + G x (y + 1)}, y, x]`

Comment: @J.M. - If you use a `List` bracket around the eliminate variable, you can avoid a `Solve::bdomv` warning. That is, `Solve[{0 == -x + P - G x (y + 1), 0 == -y + G x (y + 1)}, y, {x}]`

Comment: @Bob, you're right; [old habits](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Solve.html)...

Answer (score 1):

In general, this system has no solution for `y`. That's to be expected: usually for a system of two equations you need to solve for two variables. `Solve[eqn1 && eqn2, {x, y}]` yields two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In 12.2

```
eqn1 = 0 == -x + P - G x (y + 1);eqn2 = 0 == -y + G x (y + 1);
Reduce[eqn1 && eqn2, y]
```

> `(x == 0 && P == 0 && y == 0) || (x (-1 - P + x) != 0 &&  G == -((P - x)/(x (-1 - P + x))) && y == P - x)`

You may solve  `G == -((P - x)/(x (-1 - P + x)))` in `x` and then express `y` in terms of `P` and `G`. I leave it on your own.